# Using function to put values into struct in C

Tags: c, struct

Assignment requires using a function to input data into a struct

```
typedef struct AC {
    char code[4];
    double cost;
    unsigned day;
} AC;
```

My function so far is

```
int main(){
AC *ac;
input(&ac);
}

void input(AC * ac)
{
    printf_s("Input code (3 characters), cost, and day (0 = Sun 6 = Sat) separated by spaces: \n");

    gets(ac->code);
    printf_s("\nCode: %s\n", ac->code);

    scanf_s(" %lf", ac->cost);
    printf_s("\nCost: %.2lf\n", ac->cost);

    scanf_s(" %i", ac->day);
    printf_s("\nDay: %i\n", ac->day);
}
```

The gets for the airport code works fine, but the scanf for cost and day don't seem to do anything; using breakpoints, it seems like the function isn't placing the values scanf gets into the struct. Instead, cost just remains garbage code after that part is done.

Don't worry about error checking or anything, I'm just interested in how to make the function properly take the input values and put them in the struct.

Answer (score 2):

You've got undefined behavior all over. The problem is that there is no actual space for the `AC` struct you're populating. It's a simple change. Replace `AC *ac;` with `AC ac;`. That changes `ac` from a pointer to an actual struct with backing memory.

Comment: Hmm, that didn't do the trick. Now I get a write access violation when the program gets to the first scanf

Comment: @AlexSorkin See Jay Kumar R's answer.

Answer (score 1):

use & .
Like `scanf_s(" %i", &ac->day)`;

A string is character array ( char * or char [] ) So it does not require &. But non-arrays require it.

Also you should declare `AC ac;` (as Michael Arbers pointed out first) then pass the address `( &ac)` when calling the function call. That is because you are passing address and declared the function to take pointer to AC (AC *ac).

In C language, when you declare an address variable (pointer) you use * . When fetching the address you use &  .

Comment: Alex , it may have helped you, but to understand you have to read more and understand and take baby steps. good luck.